# Xcode 7.1.1 Error - No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found

Tags: xcode, xcode7, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have a game in Unity 5 and exported iOS build. Opened the project in Xcode and selected correct Team and Provisioning Profile. Xcode than shows an error ***"Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found"***.

I checked Apple Ids in *Preferences->Accounts* and found that its showing a ***Reset*** button for all the Signing Identities including *iOS Distribution* except *iOS Development*.

I have private key showing in Keychain for the team, both for development and distribution.

WWDR certificate was expired, so I deleted that and installed correct one.

I am pulling my hairs over it for more than 6 hours but no clue so far.

Please help...

[image: Xcode Signing Identities section]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your bundle identifier is same as that of provisioning profile?

Comment: Can you show the code signing section of your project build settings?

Comment: Attached screenshots of the same. Also, one of my colleague using same developer profile properly (previously he was also using 7.1.1 and recently updated to 7.3). And I also tried importing the developer profile, exported from his Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create your developer distribution certificate once again and installed it.

Check there will be any default provisioning profile like start with * or generated by xcode then delete it and generate once again and installed.

Its working fine..

Comment: I am afraid if creating the developer / distribution certificate may cause affect on other running games. As we have other games which are already on App Store, and same certificate is working fine on another mac os x, so why not on my mac os x. Can't we find any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted all the certificates/provisioning profiles and imported it fresh in xcode and it worked. Don't know why but it worked.. :)